# How to use javax.ws.rs.core.Feature with CXF?

Tags: java, spring, jax-rs, cxf

I would like to use a JAX-RS Feature I created with CXF.

I would prefer to use a JAX-RS Feature (`javax.ws.rs.core.Feature`) if possible and not a CXF Feature (`org.apache.cxf.feature.Feature`).
I would also prefer to use SpringComponentScanServer (`org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.SpringComponentScanServer`) to configure CXF rather than having to create the server factory or servers manually.

Here is how I tried to configure CXF:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider;
import com.mycustomapp.restexception.providers.RestExceptionFeature;
import org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.spring.SpringComponentScanServer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;

@Configuration
@Import(SpringComponentScanServer.class)
public class CxfConfiguration
{
    @Bean
    public RestExceptionFeature restExceptionFeature()
    {
        return new RestExceptionFeature();
    }

    @Bean
    public JacksonJsonProvider jacksonJsonProvider()
    {
        return new JacksonJsonProvider();
    }
}
```

Here is my custom feature:

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Feature;
import javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;

@Provider
public class RestExceptionFeature implements Feature
{
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context)
    {
        context.register(RestExceptionBodyReader.class);
        context.register(RestExceptionMapper.class);
        context.register(RestExceptionCxfClientMapper.class);

        return true;
    }
}
```

`RestExceptionFeature.configure()` is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Created ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CXF-6879
My code should work in CXF 3.1.7 when it is released.

It is working now if I use CXF 3.1.7-SNAPSHOT or CXF 3.2.0-SNAPSHOT from http://repository.apache.org/snapshots/